# Spanning tree with exactly a1+a2=n edges

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, spanning-tree

This question is very similar to this one: [spanning tree with exactly k colored edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363403/spanning-tree-with-exactly-k-colored-edges)

**It's not the same question!** - As you can see the answer of the question above is not the same (to my Q)....

We have a connected, undirected graph `G=(V,E)` with edges that are each either red or blue.

We know that `|V|=n`. We get two numbers: `a1,a2∈N` where `a1` is for the red edges, and `a2` is for the blue edges. `a1+a2=n−1`.

We have to find an algorithm that checks if there is a spanning tree that have exactly `a1` red edges and `a2` blue edges. If not, the algorithm returns that there is no spanning tree with this condition.

I tried to get help from the question mentioned above, but I am still stuck.
I assume these are very similar questions.

Comment: But the question is different!
Here we have to find an edges with **two** colors that are spanning tree and we have a condition....
Please don't mark as duplicate!!
This question don't have the same answer... :-(

Comment: Yes, it does. Read it more carefully and do some algebra.